# Mac OS Keychain with SMTP email password

Tags: osx, email, passwords

How do I get Emacs to use the Mac OS Keychain for my SMTP email password?

I'd like to eschew an .authinfo file in favour of the Mac OS Keychain
but can't seem to get it going. I keep receiving the error `auth-source-macos-keychain-search: The MacOS Keychain auth-source backend doesn't support creation yet`.

Some relevant excerpts from my init file:

```
'(auth-sources (quote (macos-keychain-internet macos-keychain-generic)))
'(smtpmail-smtp-server "mail.example.com")
'(smtpmail-smtp-service 465)
'(smtpmail-smtp-user "user@example.com")
'(smtpmail-stream-type (quote ssl))
'(send-mail-function (quote smtpmail-send-it))
```

I have created an entry with Keychain Access in my default keychain with
the following:

- Keychain Item Name: `mail.example.com`
- Account Name: `address@hidden`
- Password: `password12345`

The following commands return the password:

```
$ security find-generic-password -l mail.example.com -a address@hidden -w
=> password12345
$ security find-generic-password -s mail.example.com -a address@hidden -w
=> password12345
```

However, if I eval

```
(auth-source-search :label "mail.example.com")
=> nil
(auth-source-search :server "mail.example.com")
= nil
(auth-source-search :label "mail.example.com" :user "address@hidden")
=> nil
```

The Mac OS authorisation popup appears, but I can't tell whether it's
returning the password...

I have the `security` retrieval method working for OfflineIMAP using the
real Keychain entry, so it's not a user/password problem.

I'm happy to switch to another `send-mail-function`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few days ago I reported a bug against Emacs for this very problem (bug [19074](http://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=19074)). If you're comfortable doing so, I'd suggest applying the patch I supplied - and please report back with your results so I can fix any problems :)

Comment: Thanks, patch works a charm. Reported more here: http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-gnu-emacs/2014-11/msg00543.html

Comment: Thank you. I created a keychain item using `security add-internet-password -a myusername@gmail.com -l smtp.gmail.com -P 587 -r smtp -s smtp.gmail.com -w my-password -U` and that worked.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't know about `auth-source-search, so I wrote this code instead, in order to extract a password from the keychain:

```
(defun get-keychain-password (service)
  "Get a generic password from the OS X keychain.
The password is associated with the string SERVICE.
This corresponds to the Account field in the Keychain Access GUI.
BUG: If there is no matching password, or the output of /usr/bin/security
is on an unexpected format, the function silently returns NIL."
  (with-temp-buffer
    (call-process "/usr/bin/security"
                  nil (list (current-buffer) t) nil
                  "find-generic-password" "-ws" service)
    (let ((max (point-max)))
      (when (> max 1)
        (buffer-substring-no-properties 1 (- max 1))))))
```

Comment: This works for retrieving a password and setting it to a variable, but `auth-source` is written to be a bit more secure, i.e. once I got `auth-source-search` working with @jbm's patch, I pushed  it to to return the password as plaintext, but it appears protected against that.

Comment: @mkn That sounds great, though I am not quite sure I understand the security aspect of what you say. Still, it's good to know I can retire my homebrewed code. I have enough of that lying around as it is …

Comment: I mean that if I eval `(setq password (get-keychain-password "mail.example.com"))` then my password would be available to any future session evaluating the `password` variable. By contrast, `auth-source` prevents this with some `cl` layer magic.